# JMS queue redelivery order in jboss

Tags: jms, hornetq

I send a java object to a queue from a thread. The relavent MDB's onMessage is invoked with a message from the queue. onMessage, I match a key present in the message with a key in a cache, if key is not present I throw a custom runtimeexception just to make the container redeliver this message. (I have another autonomous system that adds key to the cache from the external system response, it may be little slow by 3-5 seconds) 
In such case, does this container add this unprocessed message to the end of the queue, or is it redelivered immediately? is there a way to delay the redelivery time? assuming the queue is always filled with ~550 messages every second.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's current a redelivery delay feature on HornetQ but all the subsequent messages are delivered fine.

There's a feature request in place to hold the queue for some time if a redelivery happens but that has not been implemented yet.

but if you have multiple consumers on the queue the order will be spread with your consumers anyways. You could use message-grouping and add a sleep on your onMessage if deliveryCount > 1. The message grouping is to guarantee no other consumer (or another MDB instance) will receive the messages out of order.

Depending on how you're application is done, and depending on your requirements you may want to only allow a single instance of your MDB.

Also: look at the consumer-window-size where you can select no buffering on the client which has a better behaviour when you have multiple consumers or multiple mdb instances.